# How to make the android activity title editable?

Tags: android, manifest

Can someone help me make the title of my activity editable? I have this note taking app where I want to be able to add a title to the specific note that I want to add. I have tried using the id of the EditText from the menu as label in the Manifest.xml but it doesn’t work.

Sample code for the menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">   

    <item 
        android:title="Ok" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white_48dp" 
        android:id="@+id/note_details_save" 
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item 
        android:title="back" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_back_button" 
        android:id="@+id/note_details_back" 
        android:orderInCategory="0" 
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/note_details_title"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Answer (score 0):

Use setTitle("My title") by itself in your activity.

"My title" should be the content of your editText.

```
String title = et.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**styles.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="8dp" app:elevation="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Editable title]

Answer (score 0):

@Mel

I have no idea why no one has answered this properly. Here is the solution:

in the layout file of the activity(where u want the editable title). Add a editText inside your toolbar tag. It should look something  like this(using support-library):
(Important: What's important to notice here is the editText inside your toolbar, don't worry too much about the attributes of the other tags).

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/yourId"
                android:hint="yourHint"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Now on the onCreate method of said activity disable the default uneditable title:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

If u want control the positioning of the editText inside the toolbar, you can wrap it in a ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout.

That's it... good luck to you all